# Authenticating via Github (using everyauth)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth, everyauth

I'm using [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth), and am having trouble authenticating it with github. It seems like all of the steps I've followed thus far are correct, but it keeps telling me it `cannot GET /auth/github` when clicking the "connect with github" link.

Here's a gist with my code: https://gist.github.com/2641260

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its probably too late to answer, but I just had the same problem and figured out the solution.

Its really simple.

Place the EveryAuth code before the app.configure() code.

This way: [Fork of your Gist](https://gist.github.com/3667481)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but have you tried adding the ".entryPath" chainable parameter?

```
everyauth.github
    .entryPath('/auth/github')
    .appId("APP_ID")
    .appSecret("APP_SECRET")
    .findOrCreateUser( function (sess, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, ghUser) {
  console.log('find user')
  // return usersByGhId[ghUser.id] || (usersByGhId[ghUser.id] = addUser('github', ghUser));
  })
 .redirectPath('/');
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, @steve, but unfortunately that didn't help. I appreciate it, though!